# how to route url having QueryString to specific ActionResult of Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 3 in C# and I want to route the URL consisting of `QueryString` to desired controller and action Method.
URL will be like `localhost:44578/HVAC/?pos=installer` I want to route this. I don't know how to do that.
I am new to MVC.

default route in RouteConfig is

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{siteName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SeoTree", 
                action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I want to create new Map route which routes the url to `Contoller = "SeoTree" ,action ="PositionInAll"`

Answer (score 2):

just map the route as you wanted like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Custom",
    "{controller}/{action}/{pos}",
    new { controller = "seoTree", action = "PositionInAll"},
    new { pos = @"\d+" }
    );
```

Comment: jack.the.ripper It's still not working. It is using default ActionResult of that controller

Comment: Well that means you have a conflict with other route

Comment: well I have one another route routes.MapRoute(
                "State",
                "{siteName}/{stateName}",
                new { controller = "SeoTree", action = "Cities" }
                );

Comment: I don't see any stateName defined in your route, that could be the reason to the conflict, maybe if you change stateName by action should do the trick!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that.

Comment: try this route ===> routes.MapRoute( "State", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "SeoTree", action = "Cities" } ); and the other i suggested

Comment: post both of your routes and also post the debug routes table